# PDA for the language of strings containing the same number of a and b

Tags: pushdown-automata

Need idea for solving the following pushdown automata:

$\mathcal{L}=\{w\in\sum ^* | \#a(w)=\#b(w),|w|\geqslant 0\}  \,\,\,\, \sum=\{a,b\}$

In the beginning I thought to PUSH *A* for input *a*, and then to POP *A* for input *b*, but it doesn't work well for the word ba for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have solved half of the task. Now push $B$ for $b$ and pop $B$ for $a$.
To decide which operation to do, handle empty stack, pushing symbol when it is empty and popping otherwise.